# Get the value of first input in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8"  id="SearchPatient">
   <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Patient suchen .." type="text">
</form>
```

And this JavaScript function:

```
$("#SearchPatient").submit(function () {
    Patient.all(1, this.find('input').value)
});
```

How you can guess i try o achieve that when the user submits the form the value of the input is passed to the function `Patient.all(int,value)`

Somehow i cant figure out how to get the first input in the form, i always get errors! For this code example i get the error:

> Object # has no method 'find'

How can i do it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$(this).find('input').val();
```

We need to pass **this** in the jquery function to make use of the jquery methods

*Update: as comment , to get the first-*

`$(this).find('input:first').val();`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a $( ).

The correct code should be:

`$("#SearchPatient").submit(function(){Patient.all(1,$(this).find('input').value)});`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first input child of your form use

```
$(this).children("input[type='text']:first").val();
```